# I would like to create a variety of conditional statements in flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a card logic using `ListView.separated` in Flutter. What I want to implement here is, the current date is implemented in gray. However, the issue lies in the logic for changing the card color only for the clicked dates.

This is my code:

```
 Container date_card(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.13,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
        child: ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            // Today date
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
            DateTime startOfWeek =
                currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: currentDate.weekday + 1));

            DateTime itemDate = startOfWeek.add(Duration(days: index));
            String formattedDate = DateFormat('d').format(itemDate);
            String formattedDay = DateFormat('E').format(itemDate);


            bool isToday =
                formattedDate == DateFormat('d').format(currentDate) &&
                    formattedDay == DateFormat('E').format(currentDate);
        .
            int selectedCardIndex = -1;
            bool isSelected = selectedCardIndex == index;
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCardIndex = index;
                  selectedCardIndex > 0 ? isSelected : false;
                });
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 2,
                  color: isToday
                      ? Color(0xff9a9a9a)
                      : isSelected
                          ? Colors.black
                          : Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.12,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          formattedDate,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: isToday || isSelected
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          formattedDay.toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: isToday
                                ? Colors.white
                                : isSelected
                                    ? Colors.black
                                    : Color(0xff8EA0B6),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          (isToday && isSelected) ? '˚' : '',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              SizedBox(width: 4),
          itemCount: 30,
        ));
  }
```

I used a regular expression, and the part I focused on is the onTap section.
Through this part, I made it return true when the value is less than 0, and I intended to give black color and white text only to those where isSelected is true.

```
 onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCardIndex = index;
                  selectedCardIndex > 0 ? isSelected : false;
                });
...

Text(
                          formattedDate,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: isToday || isSelected
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),

                        Text(
                          formattedDay.toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: isToday
                                ? Colors.white
                                : isSelected
                                    ? Colors.black
                                    : Color(0xff8EA0B6),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          (isToday && isSelected) ? '˚' : '',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        )
```

I attempted to use a regular expression for the conditional statement, but all attempts failed. I want the card to change to a black background when clicked, and return to its original state when clicked again. How can I achieve this? Please provide advice.

Comment: "regular expression" is not what you think it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring all variables within the function which is pointless because after a `setState` it will just go to the line

```
int selectedCardIndex = -1;
```

again. So you need to declare it outside the function.

Also, this line:

```
selectedCardIndex > 0 ? isSelected : false;
```

does nothing at all. You are saying it's returning a value but it's not. Maybe you are thinking of `kotlin` where the last expression in a block is the return value, this doesn't happen in `dart`. But it wouldn't matter anyway because you can't return any values from a `setState`.

I'm not entirely sure if you needed that only one item is selectable or more, but if it's just one then as I said you need to declare `selectedCardIndex` outside the function and you can change the `onTap` to

```
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedCardIndex = isSelected ? -1 : index;
            });
          },
```

If you want to able to select multiple you could use a set instead for example, so declare

```
Set<int> selectedIndexes = {};
```

(outside the function) and this as `onTap`

```
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (selectedIndexes.contains(index)){
                selectedIndexes.remove(index);
              } else {
                selectedIndexes.add(index);
              }
            });
          },
```

and change `isSelected` to

```
        bool isSelected = selectedIndexes.contains(index);
```

Comment: I express my sincere gratitude for your kind review.  :) However, I have a question. What is the difference between the initial code you provided and the setState code you suggested later?Is it true for multiple selections?

Comment: the first code only allows for a single card to be selected and the second one allows multiple selections

Answer (score 2):

i took a quick look at the provided code:

you have declared many local variables on the itemBuilder method of the listview:

```
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            // Today date
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
            DateTime startOfWeek =
                currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: currentDate.weekday + 1));

            DateTime itemDate = startOfWeek.add(Duration(days: index));
            String formattedDate = DateFormat('d').format(itemDate);
            String formattedDay = DateFormat('E').format(itemDate);


            bool isToday =
                formattedDate == DateFormat('d').format(currentDate) &&
                    formattedDay == DateFormat('E').format(currentDate);
        .
            int selectedCardIndex = -1;
            bool isSelected = selectedCardIndex == index;
            return InkWell();
}
```

**all of the above variables are locally declared and all of the listview items depend on.**
eg: if it works (toggles selection mode), then it will work only on all items.

in more simple way: if the card is white and the users clicked then all of the items will be black because all depend on local variable called isSelected.

**first Fix**

make a customized card that has a selection flag.
hence, `onTap(){just reverse the selected flag only for the current card}`.

btw: i think this line doesn't do any thing

```
    onTap(){
selectedCardIndex > 0 ? isSelected : false;
}
```

even if you reversed `isSelected` in the above `onTap()`, this cause builder to be called again and again declaring local vars

```
int selectedCardIndex = -1;
bool isSelected = selectedCardIndex == index;
```

so, again become unSelected.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) then, s it better to declare the variables globally rather than locally in this function?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code I have tried it, and it is working according to my understanding let me know if I got the logic wrong.

```js
class MyTiles extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTiles({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTiles> createState() => _MyTilesState();
}

class _MyTilesState extends State<MyTiles> {
  Container date_card(BuildContext context ,List<int> selectedCards ) {

    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.13,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
        child: ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            // Today date
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
            DateTime startOfWeek =
                currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: currentDate.weekday + 1));

            DateTime itemDate = startOfWeek.add(Duration(days: index));
            String formattedDate = DateFormat('d').format(itemDate);
            String formattedDay = DateFormat('E').format(itemDate);

            bool isToday =
                formattedDate == DateFormat('d').format(currentDate) &&
                    formattedDay == DateFormat('E').format(currentDate);

            int selectedCardIndex = -1;
            bool isSelected = selectedCardIndex == index;
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCardIndex = index;
                  selectedCardIndex > 0 ? isSelected : false;

                  if (selectedCards.contains(index)) {
                    selectedCards.remove(index);
                  } else {
                    selectedCards.add(index);
                  }
                  setState(() {

                  });
                  print(selectedCards);

                });
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 2,
                  color: selectedCards.contains(index) ?  Colors.black : isToday
                      ? Color(0xff9a9a9a)
                      : isSelected
                          ? Colors.black
                          : Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.12,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          formattedDate,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: selectedCards.contains(index) ?  Colors.white : isToday || isSelected
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          formattedDay.toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: selectedCards.contains(index) ?  Colors.white :isToday
                                ? Colors.white
                                : isSelected
                                    ? Colors.black
                                    : Color(0xff8EA0B6),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          (isToday && isSelected) ? '˚' : '',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              SizedBox(width: 4),
          itemCount: 30,
        ));
  }

  dynamic mySelectedCards= [1];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            date_card(context,mySelectedCards),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't show you the entire code. However, I've provided a brief excerpt that is relevant to the issue at hand. I hope you understand. 